# Jquery .load() Post + array of variables

Tags: jquery, post

I have the following code to load a file and send post data at the same time:

```
$('#mainContainerDIV #searchresults #'+type).load(
    'scripts/php/searchresults.php', 
    {var1:x, var2:y, var3:z}, 
    function() { ...
```

With this I can get the post data so this works fine.

This is for a search page where a person can select many different options to have in their search - from male/female gender, age ranges, locations etc.

I need to build an array (or something) with their selection and then add this to the post.

eg:

```
// Gender Males
if($('#searchSimpleSubOptionMalesActiveIMG').is(':visible')) {
    alert('yes males');
}else{
    alert('no males');
}

// Gender Females
if($('#searchSimpleSubOptionFemalesActiveIMG').is(':visible')) {
    alert('yes females');
}else{
    alert('no females');
}
```

What would be a good way for me to gather this data (user search preference) and then add it to the POST send on the `.load()`? I'm looking for an efficient way to gather and send this data.

Comment: Stick it in a form and use serialize()

Comment: Yes I have it in a form. with serialize() do I put it all into an array and then serialize()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Make an empty array:

```
var data = [];
```

Then check the options:

```
// Gender Males
if($('#searchSimpleSubOptionMalesActiveIMG').is(':visible')) {
    data['male'] = 'yes';
}else{
    data['male'] = 'no';
}
```

Finally send them:

```
$('#mainContainerDIV #searchresults #'+type).load(
    'scripts/php/searchresults.php', 
    data, 
    function() { ...
```

Comment: looks great and thankyou... just one questions (but I will test) - can I send the data[] array directly in the POST or do I need to serialize it? thx again

Comment: Yes, you can send it directly

Comment: This didn't work for me but defining data as an object (`data = {};`) and setting `data.male` worked to send the data via `$.get(url, data, ...)`.